# ssh session dies after three hours on inactivity

Tags: linux, ssh

I usually leave my PuTTY terminal window open during the day and lock the screen when I go to lunch or leave to go offsite.  Lately though when I come back, my ssh session had died.  Even though I use the keep alive from within PuTTY and have the keep alive in the sshd_config, it still occurs.

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveCountMax 99999
```

And in the auth log I saw:

```
Jun 18 15:31:52 blarg sshd[6830]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user jonathan
```

I don't have a `TMOUT` value set in `/etc/profile`

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you administer the destination site?  or the firewall and routers?  Perhaps there is an idle timeout in that chain.  I'd try contacting your site administrator.

Comment: Did you mean ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax ?

Comment: @Andrew - I should think not.  Those go in the ssh_config or the .ssh/config of the client, not the server.  He's using PuTTY though so they don't apply.

Comment: I am root on the server.  The server is hosted on a virtual dedicated host.  Its a mail/webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using putty there are some things you can actually do right there in the client.

Open putty and in the options panel load the session definition that you're using for that saved connection.

Under connection change the fiend "Sending null packets to keep sessions active" from 0 to something else (this is in seconds, so 1800 is 30 minutes)

Check "Enable TCP keepalives" (this isn't in old versions of putty, update if you don't have it)
Save your session.

Comment: Keep alive was set to 30 seconds but the TCP wasn't ticked.  I will try that now instead.

Comment: Nope, connection was aborted.  So, since it isn't PuTTY, and not the sshd_config, you think it is the firewall?  I left it idle in two spots and both connections died out after some time.

Comment: Yep, there's going to be a connection time out on the firewall.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it works now, thanks.

Comment: Way after the fact (sorry!)... but I started having a similar issue just recently: my ssh session from previous evening forcibly closed.  This despite formerly-working: "keep alive" measures on client-side, plus TCPKeepAlive et al host-side.  ...  Turns out someone had changed my Power / Energy Saver settings and my computer was now sleeping (vs. previous power-down of just display, disks).  If there's no CPU/NIC active to send idle/null packets, your firewall will indeed kill your TCP session.  I know, seems stupid, but sometimes it's the stupidest things... ;-)